# array of object is not rendering in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrayobject

I am trying to render array of object using the `map` method, but it gives an error message

> list.map is not a function

How I can render this?

The array object I want to render is:

```
let list= [
{
    "id": "8xI09EfZGldA3wMEdwUW",
    "users": ["dstha221@gmail.com", "dstha221@gmail.com"],
    "timestamp": {
        "seconds": 1639825713,
        "nanoseconds": 687000000
    }
},
{
    "id": "PiDJjjeH0eubfLz2WIe5",
    "timestamp": {
        "seconds": 1639825709,
        "nanoseconds": 341000000
    },
    "users": ["rabina@gmail.com", "dstha221@gmail.com"]
},
{
    "id": "ayAFmLpIGdUHYe8fiVvb",
    "timestamp": {
        "seconds": 1639825712,
        "nanoseconds": 291000000
    },
    "users": ["jeevan@gmail.com", "dstha221@gmail.com"]
}
];




 list.map((user)=>{
    console.log(user.id);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

cuz list: [{data}] is not an array.
fix your code like this.

```
const list = [{data}, {data}, {data}, ...]
..//
{list.map(data => <Component data={data}/>);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is not clear i will assume two cases for the data you are trying to map.

**Case One**

Assuming your data-list is of the form ..

```
const list = [{"id":"8xI09EfZGldA3wMEdwUW","users":["dstha221@gmail.com","dstha221@gmail.com"],"timestamp":{"seconds":1639825713,"nanoseconds":687000000}},{"id":"PiDJjjeH0eubfLz2WIe5","timestamp":{"seconds":1639825709,"nanoseconds":341000000},"users":["rabina@gmail.com","dstha221@gmail.com"]},{"id":"ayAFmLpIGdUHYe8fiVvb","timestamp":{"seconds":1639825712,"nanoseconds":291000000},"users":["jeevan@gmail.com","dstha221@gmail.com"]}]
```

You can then display the ids like this on your return statement ....

```
list.map((item)=> <p>{item.id}</p>)
```

**Case Two**

Asuming your list is a property of an object of the form ....

```
const myObj = {
      list: [{"id":"8xI09EfZGldA3wMEdwUW","users":["dstha221@gmail.com","dstha221@gmail.com"],"timestamp":{"seconds":1639825713,"nanoseconds":687000000}},{"id":"PiDJjjeH0eubfLz2WIe5","timestamp":{"seconds":1639825709,"nanoseconds":341000000},"users":["rabina@gmail.com","dstha221@gmail.com"]},{"id":"ayAFmLpIGdUHYe8fiVvb","timestamp":{"seconds":1639825712,"nanoseconds":291000000},"users":["jeevan@gmail.com","dstha221@gmail.com"]}]
```

Then you can map the object like this ....

```
myObj.list.map((item)=> <p>{item.id}</p>)
  }
```

Comment: not working.Agaim same error message...

Comment: if your list is gotten from an external resource or you set the list variable by any chance then you should check if by chance list is not an array, please provide full code snippet of your react component